# Count same entries per day

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

I got the following data in my table:

```
date, playerid
2015-05-05, 1
2015-05-05, 1
2015-05-05, 1
2015-05-05, 2
2015-05-05, 2
2015-05-06, 1
2015-05-06, 1
2015-05-08, 1
2015-05-08, 2
```

Now I would like to count the same entries (player-id) per day, so the result should look like this:

```
date, playerid
2015-05-05, 1
2015-05-05, 2
2015-05-06, 1
2015-05-08, 1
2015-05-08, 1
```

The important thing is, that I would like to have double date-entrys for each player-id per day.

How can I solve this?

Comment: have you looked into aggregate functions? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: Come on. Try something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though your sample output doesn't contain a "count", I'm assuming you would like it to have a count-per-player-per-day. If that's true, you'll be interested in [`GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) and [`COUNT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count):

```
SELECT
    `date`, playerid, COUNT(*) AS `count`
FROM
    your_table
GROUP BY
    `date`, playerid
ORDER BY
    `date`, playerid
```

If you're interested in *only* the players that have multiple entries for a single day, check out [`HAVING`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html):

```
SELECT
    `date`, playerid
FROM
    your_table
GROUP BY
    `date`, playerid
HAVING
    COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY
    `date`, playerid
```

Comment: Oh, in my example there's one row missing: I would like to count the count-per-player-per-day. 

Your solution is working great - thank you very much :-)